# Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle

Execution failed:

> task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CompressAssetsWorkAction   > \app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For me what did the job was

```
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a temporary solution in downgrading my Android Studio version to 4.0.2.
Additionally, I changed the Android Gradle plugin version to 4.0.2 and the Gradle version to 6.1.1 which I had installed before. You can do this under
File -> Project Structure -> Project.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me because I had **too large a file** inside my assets folder. In my case it was a .db file

Comment: I think that it would be nice if you added how you fixed it. I fix it by changing the line in `android/gradle.properties` from `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2536M`

Answer (score 4):

deleted .gradle .idea

having your project in this folder the original of the program
AndroidStudioProjects

open Project
File > Invalidate Caches /Resetart..

Android studio will restart
File > Sync Projet With Gradle Files

end..

my current project
Android Gradle Pluglin version 4.3.3
Gradle version 6.7.1

Comment: I did not changed any plugin or gradle version it is by default 7+ version for gradle. tried all the steps above and worked for me after 2 days struggle!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to solve the problem in AndoidStudio as follows:
Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem.

I was saving my folder to a mapped drive (i.e. my mapped Google drive `e:\\Google Drive`).  It failed every time.  I then moved the folder to the `c:` drive and everything worked fine.

So if you are saving it to a mapped drive, it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by changing the settings in android/app/build.gradle file as follows:

```
minSdkVersion 28
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building my project for the first time using android-studio arm version, what fixed it a simple ./gradlew clean as illgoforit mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, solutions to this error, sound and look a bit like crystal ball sight seeing!!!!

So here's mine:

Was able to solve it by running delete folders

```
/app/build
/.ideia
/.gradle
```

moved the project to a NFFS partition on windows.

invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio and then rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

Running `flutter clean` in a terminal window from the project root directory fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve only by updating the Flutter

in your terminal run: "flutter upgrade"